# Play waiting music in the background during the Twilio Call

Tags: twilio

I am facing a small issue, I am using twilio in my application. When a caller calls on twilio number, I search the database for a match against the incoming number. If a match is found an action is taken otherwise the caller is directed to a different number.

The problem is sometimes the database query takes more time (5-7 secs) and during that time the caller hears nothing but silence. I want to play waiting music during that time.

I have read about the  tab in twilio but still haven't figured out how to incorporate it in my existing system.

Here are my files

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
            echo '<Response>';

                    echo '<Play>audio/Welcome.mp3</Play>';
                    echo '<Play>audio/Option.mp3</Play>';
                    echo '<Redirect method="POST">http://www.server.com/autoConfirmation/IvrCallRouting.php</Redirect>';

            echo '</Response>';
```

In IvrCallRouting.php

```
$matchNumber = DatabaseQuery($_Request['From']);
if($matchNumber == ''){
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response>';
echo "<Dial><Number>MyPhoneNumber</Number></Dial>";  
echo '</Response>';
}
else{
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
 echo '<Response>';
 echo "<Dial><Number>$matchNumber</Number></Dial>";  
 echo '</Response>';
}
```

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not much of a PHP programmer, is there a way you could make that database call in the background, or asynchronously to the TwiML response? Alternatively, is there a way you can make your DB query faster? Perhaps an index on the phone number column?

Comment: No I am afraid that doesn't fit in with our application, as I mentioned in the problem statement, I have read about the <Enqueue> verb but don't know how to use it in my application. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: `<Enqueue>` puts the user into a Queue while waiting for an agent to become available to take the call. You're just trying to forward the caller to a number based on a database lookup. Unless you're looking for something a bit more complex. I'm still worried about your database taking 5-7 seconds to do a lookup based on a phone number though. Are you sure there's nothing that can be done to improve that speed?

Comment: I am sure, before optimizing my query it was taking more than 10 secs and call used to get dropped. So we optimized our database tables and did everything to make sure that least time was taken by the db. But still in some cases(when traffic is high) it takes db a bit more time and our caller drops the call because of the delay. 
It would be nice If I can play some background music in that time.

Comment: Ok, so the call drops because Twilio has a 15 second timeout for webhooks. You need to respond with some TwiML immediately (using `<Play>` for example) and do this lookup in the background somehow, then once you have the result from the database, [redirect the call to the next step](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls). As I said, I don't know how to perform background tasks in PHP, so I can't help there.